# how to set up basic AsyncCommand with Task in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Tools:** I am using Xamarin.form MVVM.

**Question:** How do I set up basic AsyncCommand command with Task?

**Debug:** I am not getting any error, when I click on button, Displaybox alert doesnt show up. I check and addcommand method is not getting runned on tap.

**Bind:** I also have bind View with ViewModel

```
 BindingContext = new ProductViewModel();
```

I watched a tutorial by microsoft and there seem to be working just fine. Did I missed something?

**View Page**

```
<Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
```

**ViewModel Page**

```
public class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       ...
      public AsyncCommand AddComamnd { get; }
       
      public ProductViewModel()
      {
        ...
        AddComamnd = new AsyncCommand(OnAddComamnd);
       }

  public async Task OnAddComamnd()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
      // I have also tried both (App and Application) neither works
    }
}
```

Comment: "AddComamnd" and "{Binding AddCommand}" are spelled differently

Comment: lol thanks! fixed... weird i didnt got any errors @Jason

Comment: There won't be any compile error in VS, but if you set a breakpoint in your method, it never stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, first of all there's a lot of typo, you put AddCommand here:

```
<Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
```

So you need same command name:

```
public Command AddCommand { get; }
```

Then:

```
public ProductViewModel()
{
    ...
    AddCommand = new Command(async () => await OnAddComamnd()); //OnAddCommamnd is your async task
}
```

you can watch about command in here: [Episode 5: MVVM & Data Binding with Xamarin.Forms](https://youtu.be/GZDQptTQZsk) start at minute 22